# Image views in Xcode not displaying correctly on build

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I can't seem to get 4 Image views to display correctly when I run the app.

I'm in wCompact/hRegular (iPhone app). I set constraints for width and height. For spacing I selected the correct brackets for each box. For example I set TopRight box margin 45 from Right, 245 from Top. From the drop down I make sure View is selected. Did this for all 4. Here is what it looks like in xcode and then after I run it. What am I doing wrong? They do not show up correctly spaced and the top boxes are cut off.

[The constraints I add per Image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfJiO.png)

[All constraints in Compact Reg...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oDQV.png)

Comment: add width and height or aspect ratio constraints to imageViews.

Comment: I did add width and height, 150 x 150 for each. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Looks like you have some conflicting constraints

Comment: Try removing all constraints and select all the views and from Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> AddMissingConstraints. See if it helps.

Comment: That didn't seem to help either. After trying that the bottom imageViews are now cut off instead of the top ones. Just like in the picture I posted earlier.

Comment: Go to your storyboard select the controller which is troubling you , press cmd+A (this will show all the contraints) then take a screenshot , post it here :)

Comment: It is happening because you have set wrong constraints to the image views.

Comment: I've added two more pictures to original post. I had to delete my first two pictures since I don't have enough rep to post more then 2 links at a time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was spacing all of them 245 from the top & bottom assuming vertically the whole screen was 500 (leaving a gap of 5 between them at center. I was assuming this would center them vertically the same distance apart but that isn't the case. I just had to move the bottom ones down some. However it doesn't look right on all phone sims. For example it looks fine on 6s but not on 6. Why is this? I assumed if I'm in compact regular it would look correct for all iPhones.

Comment: Sorry meant 6s Plus compared to 6.

Comment: Just following up on this as I didn't hear back after updating my pictures with the requested ones. Thank you